# How to delete a row because it has only one or the same entry in the other column?

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I have prepared a small example:[exp.pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv1Th.png)

[image]

I want to delete the lines of Opel because Opel is present twice with the same model.And ford occurs only once.

I just want to have the cars with at least two different models.

```
Car<-c("Audi","Audi","BMW","BMW","Mercedes","Opel","Ford","Audi","BMW","Mercedes","Audi","BMW","Mercedes","Opel")
Model<-c("A4","A4","X5","X5","E","Astra","Fiesta","A6","M3","C","A6","530","A","Astra")

Car<-cbind(Car,Model)
Car<-data.frame(Car)
```

### Output should look like this:

[image]

And for example it is all right that Audi A4 appears five times as long as there is another model of audi.

I hope I could explain it well.

Comment: I added a picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another attempt with `dplyr`:

```
Car %>%
  group_by(Car) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(Model) > 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(Car, Model)

# # A tibble: 11 x 2
#  Car      Model
#  <fct>    <fct>
#  1 Audi     A4   
#  2 Audi     A4   
#  3 Audi     A6   
#  4 Audi     A6   
#  5 BMW      530  
#  6 BMW      M3   
#  7 BMW      X5   
#  8 BMW      X5   
#  9 Mercedes A    
# 10 Mercedes C    
# 11 Mercedes E
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `subset` we can filter for car companies with more than one unique model.

```
out <- subset(Cars, ave(Model, Car, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) > 1)
out
#        Car Model
#1      Audi    A4
#2      Audi    A4
#3       BMW    X5
#4       BMW    X5
#5  Mercedes     E
#8      Audi    A6
#9       BMW    M3
#10 Mercedes     C
#11     Audi    A6
#12      BMW   530
#13 Mercedes     A
```

**data**

```
Cars <- data.frame(Car, Model, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#  ^ note the different name
```